# jquery.iframetracker Não funciona no Mozilla Firefox, tem como resolver?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

eu tenho um script que grava um cookie com ajax quando se clica em um anuncio do Google (iframe), Funciona no Google Chrome de boa.. porem no firefox não.. alguém sabe o porque ? Ou se tem outra solução para fazer a mesma coisa que estou querendo fazer...

```html
<?php
 $url = parse_url($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
 parse_str($url["query"],$queryString);
  //setcookie("novo_ads","sim", time() + 172800,  $path = "/"); // 86400 = 1 dia, 172800 = 2 dias (SEGUNDOS)
?>
<style media="screen">
  body {
    background: rgb(218,234,237); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(218,234,237,1) 0%, rgba(252,248,231,1) 44%, rgba(237,247,228,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(218,234,237,1) 0%,rgba(252,248,231,1) 44%,rgba(237,247,228,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(218,234,237,1) 0%,rgba(252,248,231,1) 44%,rgba(237,247,228,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#daeaed', endColorstr='#edf7e4',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100% !important;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    min-height: auto !important;
    color: #000000bf !important;
  }
  @media (max-width: 640px) {
    .container {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
</style>

<?php if (!isset($_COOKIE['novo_ads'])): ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
      <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.iframetracker/1.1.0/jquery.iframetracker.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- HTML -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="epaco" style="margin: 20px;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
              <center>
                <h2 style="font-weight: bold;"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i> DOWNLOAD BLOQUEADO <i class="fas fa-lock"></i></h2>
              </center>
            </div>

            <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
              <center>
                Clique em um dos anúncios abaixo e <b>aguarde 20 segundos na pagina do anunciante</b> para liberar, e depois clique no botão no final da pagina.<br>
                <b>TUTORIAL</b>: Caso ainda não esteja dando conta de passar por essa etapa, <a href="#" target="_blank">clique aqui</a> para ver um vídeo com passo a passo de como passar.
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="anuncio">
              <center>
                ADS GOOGLE
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="anuncio">
              <center>
                ADS GOOGLE
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
            <div class="anuncio">
              <center>
                ADS GOOGLE
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
              <center>
                Caso tenha feito todo passo a passo acima, agora e só clicar no botão abaixo para liberar seu download.<br>
                <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fas fa-lock-open"></i> LIBERAR DOWNLOAD</button></a>
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- SCRIPTS -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery.noConflict();
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          interval_id = window.setInterval(function() {
          // verifica que o iframe existe ou ja foi carregado
          if( jQuery('.anuncio iframe').length > 0 ) {
              jQuery('.anuncio iframe').iframeTracker({
                  blurCallback: function(){
                      $.ajax({
                         method: "POST",
                         url: "https://uploadbr.onlinee.top/noticias/gravacookieclique.php",
                         data: { gravaCookieclique: "sim"}
                      });
                      console.log('consegui');
                  }
              });
              // limpa intervalo
              clearInterval(interval_id);
              }
          },500);
      });
      </script>

      <!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
<?php else: ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
      <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.iframetracker/1.1.0/jquery.iframetracker.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- HTML -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="epaco" style="margin: 20px;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
              <center>
                <h2 style="font-weight: bold;">DOWNLOAD LIBERADO</h2>
              </center>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
              <center>
                Seu download foi liberado, caso não iniciei automaticamente <a href="#">clique aqui</a>.
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
            <div class="ANUNCIOFINAL">
              <center>
                ADS GOOGLE
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
              <center>
                Obrigado por deixar nosso site ainda melhor!
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
<?php endif; ?>


<script>
  window.setTimeout(function() {
 document.getElementsByClassName("loading")[0].style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementsByClassName("interface")[0].style.display = 'block';
 window.setTimeout(function() {
 if (document.getElementById("download-liberado").style.display != 'block') {
    document.getElementById("download-bloqueado").style.display = 'block';
 }
 }, 30000);
 }, 5000);
</script>
<div class="homes" style="display: none !important;">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373592/iframe-contents-cant-appear-in-firefox

Comment: Amigo, não e que não aparece... quero saber como fazer a mesma função desse plugin no Mozilla.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar esse iframeTracker jQuery Plugin?https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery  (Testei aqui e no Mozilla está disparando evento do clique em um iframe

Comment: Amigo.. e esse ai...

Comment: Só por desencargo de consciência. No seu código o plugin também é carregado antes do jQuery? Porque o jQuery deve ser carregado antes do que qualquer plugin.

Comment: Sim! soh tem o jQuery na pagina que utilizo!

Comment: qual versão do firefox você está utilizando, testei aqui com a versão 63 e foi na boa, não consegui reproduzir seu erro

Comment: Uso a mais recente! Porem funciona algumas veses..

Answer (score 1):

fiz uma modificação no seu código veja se desta forma funciona:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jquery.iframetracker/jquery.iframetracker.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    interval_id = window.setInterval(function() {
    // verifica que o iframe existe ou ja foi carregado
    if( jQuery('.anuncio iframe').length > 0 ) {
        jQuery('.anuncio iframe').iframeTracker({
            blurCallback: function(){
                $.ajax({
                   method: "POST",
                   url: "gravacookieclique.php",
                   data: { gravaCookieclique: "sim"}
                });
                console.log('consegui');
            }
        });
        // limpa intervalo
        clearInterval(interval_id);
        }
    },500);
});
</script>
```

inclui um `console.log` para printar uma msg quando enviar para o seu php

casonão funcione ainda utilize o jquery como função desta maneira

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function($) {
        // You pass-in jQuery and then alias it with the $-sign
        // So your internal code doesn't change
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Erro que me acontece: http://prntscr.com/lfue8t

Comment: vou editar o cod.

Comment: Não apareceu o erro.. porem não funcionou o log, atualizei meu código completo pra você ver.. Eu uso Bootstrap.

Comment: qual versão de jquery ta no seu boostrap?

Comment: Eu coloco a mais nova do Bootstrap 4 Porem... nada.. Por isso atualizei meu codigo ai, e coloquei ate o mesmo link do seu jquery, mas mesmo assim nada..